# Disable a Plotly Dash component inside another callback function when a condition has been met

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, callback, plotly-dash

I have a few Dash dropdown menus and Dash buttons defined.

```
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
dash_board_controller = DashBoardController() #user defined dashboard class
app.layout = make_default_view(dash_board_controller=dash_board_controller)

html.Div(
    [
        html.P("Variation", className="bare_container"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-a",
            options=[{'label': 'Option 1', 'value': 'option1'},
                 {'label': 'Option 2', 'value': 'option2'},
                 {'label': 'Option 3', 'value': 'option3'}],
            multi=True,
            value=["All"],
            clearable=False,
            className="dcc_filter",
        ),
    ],
    className="filter_div",
)

html.Div(
    [
        html.P("Variation", className="bare_container"),
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id="dropdown-b",
            options=[{'label': 'Option 1', 'value': 'option1'},
                 {'label': 'Option 2', 'value': 'option2'},
                 {'label': 'Option 3', 'value': 'option3'}],
            multi=True,
            value=["All"],
            clearable=False,
            className="dcc_filter",
        ),
    ],
    className="filter_div",
)


html.Div(
    [
        html.Button(
            id="export_button",
            children="Export Report",
            style={
                "fontSize": 14,
                "margin": "5px",
                "padding": "0px",
                "width": "90%",
                "opacity": "1"
            },
            className="button-primary"
        ),
        html.Div(id="hidden-div", style={"display": "none"}),
    ],
    className="center_flex",
)
```

When the export button is clicked, I want to the dropdown menus to be disabled by another callback function.

```
# export button callback function
@app.callback(
        Output(
            component_id="hidden-div", component_property="children"
        ),
        Input(component_id="export_button", component_property="n_clicks"),
    )
def export_report(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        
        # some conditional logic that sets condition as either true or false
        condition = True

        if condition:
            disable_dropdown_menus(n_clicks, condition)
        
        # some heavy computation

# callback function to disable the dropdown menus.
@app.callback(
        [
            Output("dropdown-a", "disabled"),
            Output("dropdown-b", "disabled"),
        ],
        [
            Input("n_clicks", "n_clicks")
        ],
        [
            State("condition", "value")
        ]
    )
def disable_dropdown_menus(_, condition):
    dropdown_a = condition
    dropdown_b = condition
    
    return dropdown_a, dropdown_b
```

I am using the **n_clicks** from **export_report** as a placeholder variable. It's the **condition** state that will disable the dropdown menus. I am getting the following error.

```
File "test.py", line 807, in export_report
    disable_dropdown_menus(n_clicks, True)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\envs\project\lib\site-packages\dash\dash.py", line 1004, in add_context
    output_spec = kwargs.pop("outputs_list")
KeyError: 'outputs_list'
```

Is there a better way to disable dropdown menus involving callbacks?

Comment: Can you provide the `app.layout` you're using please ?

Comment: I have added the app.layout initialization in the code (it's a list of HTML divs). I cannot divulge the exact contents of the app.layout as there are sensitive information. But if you need to know, go.Figure is not used to create the app layout.

Comment: in the second callback, `Input("n_clicks", "n_clicks")` is not valid

Comment: Also, can you please provide the version of Dash you're using?

Comment: Here are the dependency versions: 
   dash=1.16.3=py_0,
   dash-core-components=1.3.1=py_0,
   dash-html-components=1.0.1=py_0,
   dash-renderer=1.1.2=py_0,
   dash-table=4.4.1=pyhd3eb1b0_0,
   plotly=4.14.3=pyhd3eb1b0_0,

Comment: I'm not sure to understand why you need 2 callbacks here ? Why not just the second one ? Or merge the 2 callbacks ?

Comment: I actually have the callback function for disabling the dropdown menus when the buttons are clicked, but I don't know how to do so without using callbacks. Also if dropdown menus state changes with a return statement, then they won't be disabled when the heavy computation runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254247/discussion-between-thmslmr-and-disguisedtoast).